# Вывод файлов из папки

Tags: php

Подскажите как решить такую задачу в этом скрипте: 
Из папки вывести только файлы php и без первого символа _ (подчеркивание), убрать расширение .php в названиии файла?

```
<?php 

$dir = "album/";
$name = scandir($dir);

for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
echo "<a target=_blank href='".$dir.$name[$i]."'>".$name[$i]."</a><br/>";


}



?>
```

Измененный:

```
<?php 

$dir = "./";
$name = glob('*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);

for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
  if( substr($name[$i],0,1) != "_") {
    $shortname = substr($name[$i], 0, -4);
    $shortname = str_replace('_', ' ', $shortname);
    $shortname = ucwords($shortname);
    echo "<a target=_blank href='".$name[$i]."'>".$shortname."</a><br/>";

  }
}

?>


<p>На странице <?php 
echo count ($name);
?>  моделей
```

Comment: **count** - если нужно количество файлов, обновите задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут лучше не `scandir`, а `glob`, который сразу отберет все пхп-файлы:

```
$files = glob('/album/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

А остальное придется вручную делать:

```
$counter = 0; //заводим счетчик

for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) { 
  if( substr($name[$i],0,1) != "_") { //если файл не начинается с подчеркивания
    $shortname = substr($name[$i], 0, -4); // отрезали четыре символа с конца и точку
    $shortname = str_replace('_', ' ', $shortname); //заменили подчеркивания на пробелы
    echo "<a target=_blank href='".$dir.$name[$i]."'>".$shortname."</a><br/>";
    $counter++; //увеличиваем счетчик на единичку
  }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста: Как еще добавить замену символа _ на пробел в этих выводимых файлах.

Comment: Уоу, уоу, полегче, уже минусуют ответ. Вы тогда комментируйте, что не так. Или поправьте.

Comment: @Sergey_777, добавил код и комментарии.

Comment: @ Sergey Snegirev Спасибо! Все работает. Чуть подправил `$files = glob('/album/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);`    `$name = glob('*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);`,  а то ссылка так и выводилась   `album/Audi_Q3_2015`. А так - большое спасибо за ответ!!!

Comment: @ Sergey Snegirev Как посчитать эти выводимые файлы? Если так, `echo count ($name);` то считает кол-во файлов во всей папке, а не кол-во выводимых файлов. Выводимых в 2 раза меньше...

Comment: Добавил код счетчика. Если ответ правильный, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: `$counter = 0;  $counter++;` - если добавляю - Неработает весь скрипт. Вверху исправил скрипт...

Comment: Ищите ошибку в синтаксисе. У меня все работает : http://ideone.com/nGNlo4

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все работает!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function itsPHP($filename) {
    return end(getPart($filename)) == 'php';
  }
function getPart($filename) {
    return explode(".", $filename);
  }
function getName($filename) {
    var_dump(preg_replace('/^\_/', '', getPart($filename)[0]));
  }
$dir = "./";
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
echo "in dir <b>$dir</b> search PHP files:<br/>";
foreach ($files as $key => $name) {
    if(itsPHP($name)) {
        getName($name);
    }
}
```

дирректории `"album/";` у меня нет. Я вывожу из текущей, так что вам нужно лишь изменить переменную **$dir**

Comment: Спасибо! Но у меня скрипт не сработал.  Менял `$dir = "."; и $dir = "./"; `

Comment: @Sergey_777 **"./"** - это текущая директория, у меня **album** отсуствует, замените на необходимую

Comment: Я понял из ответа. Я этот файл в текущую и перенес... Несколько раз пробовал. Неработает!

Comment: @Sergey_777 должно работать ,убедитесь что Ваш скрипт соответствует листингу

Comment: Убрал все. Оставил только Ваш скрипт - неработает!

Comment: @Sergey_777 в скрипте вывод текста. Текст Вы увидеть должны были минимум и файл выполняемого скрипта, так что проблемы связанные с чем то другим. Гляньте в **error.log**

Comment: @Sergey_777 какая у Вас версия php? какая ОС?

Comment: PHP/5.3.29-1 System Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Fri May 10 11:48:05 UTC 2013 x86_64  Apache 2.0

Comment: @Sergey_777
похоже на то что в 5.3 для метода **scandir** второй параметр является обязательным SCANDIR_SORT_NONE
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php

Comment: @Sergey_777 обновил листинг. попробуйте так scandir($dir, 1);

Comment: На выходе пустая форма.

Comment: ладно я устал заниматься удаленным дебаггингом. Ответ у Вас есть. Вывод формы в скрипте отсуствует

Comment: В любом случае спасибо!!!

Comment: А по <p>На странице <?php 
echo count ($name);
?>  моделей  - Неподскажите? С привязкой к измененному скрипту...

Comment: @Sergey_777 что Вам нужно подсчитать? количество файлов в дирректории? количество php файлов? количество файлов которые начинались на символ "_". обновите задачу чтоб моно было понять что Вам нужно

Comment: спасибо. Скрипт добил с `counter`